# CSS Animated Circles - Stop center content from rotating

Tags: css

I've been trying to alter [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/cobk85fu) example of CSS3 animated circles (original by [Rishabh](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-animated-circles)) so that the arrow in the centre does not rotate. However, the only way I can get it be still is to remove the animation effect from the three circles (#outer-circle, #inner-circle, #centre-circle), but this gets rid of the cool spinning effect.

The circles are positioned within each other, and are rotating with the CSS below (the link to cssdeck.com is clearer)

```
-webkit-animation:turning_cw 5s infinite;
-moz-animation:turning_cw 5s infinite;
animation:turning_cw 5s infinite;
```

Does anyone know a way of getting the arrow in the centre to stay still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one method would be to break the nesting apart and stack the elements, and then position them accordingly.

I positioned each of the items as needed within the  `position:absolute;` settings adn then broke out the divs from the nesting:

HTML

```
<div id="container">    
  <div id="main">
    <div id="outer-circle"></div>
    <div id="inner-circle"></div>
    <div id="center-circle"></div>
    <div id="content">
      &darr;
    </div>
  </div>
```

RELEVANT CSS:

```
#content {
  position:absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 350px;
}

#center-circle {
  position:absolute;
    top:190px;
    left: 320px;
}

#inner-circle {
  position:absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 170px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/qglpiprm)

Comment: Thanks Phlume! Looks perfect.